# Wso2 ESB - Send many requests at the same time to a web service

Tags: java, client, benchmarking, esb, wso2-esb

How can I send many simultaneous Java requests from a Java client to a deployed web service? Knowing that the client was generated from the WSO2ESB.

Comment: Is your intention to do some kind of performance analysis of the webservice or do you just want to have a multithreaded client?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Hello Dear Sir.
My Objective is, as you said, to do a performance Analysis of the Webservice by sending Many requests in the Same time, and see the Behaviour of the ESB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to write custom logic for every request i'll prefer something like SoapUI or LoadUI. It's easy to create kind of stress test using them. 
If you need to create custom test, you can write it on your own:

1. Generate client
2. Use ThreadPool to create as many threads as you want
3. If operations on your webservice are 2-way - measure time from sending request to getting response
4. Collect statistics(this help you to understand if your esb module cope with load)

Comment: Hello.
I generated the Client through the given option by wso2 (I created an axis2 WS). Then I Obtained 2 classes One of them is called HelloServiceStub.java. I created a Normal Java class entiteled "Consumer.java" that allow to set the Provider Parameters (that give the time of treatment). I Have a question please: **Is my consumer have to be a Thread ??**

Comment: It's all as you wish details of realization can vary. When I have to cope with similar task, I created executor which run my tasks, that consumes webservice. Anyway, I'll not extend Thread, but implement Runnable. [ExecutorsService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) works with Runnable rather then Thread. Also it allows you to build your own hierarchy, without locking parent class.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- **Write your own Benchmark Driver** - this is easy and you will have a total control of what and how you measure.
- **Webservice Tools** - Webservers usually come with some form of stress-test client that you can use directly from the webserver consol, or you can try e.g. SoapUI.
- **Http Benchmark Frameworks** - use a benchmark framework that will allow you to write flexible and powerful benchmark driver. You can use :

  - [HttpBenchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) - this is an open-source HttpBenchmark that you can easily modify and use to drive workload for your Webservices/ESB.
  - [Faban](http://faban.org/) Framework, which is used to drive various webservices benchmarks (e.g. SPECjEnterprise2010). Faban is very well documented and contains tutorials which are also helpful/inspiring if you want to design your own Driver.